# How to attach handler/function to different objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Need to be enlightened as to how to define a jQuery UI slider and bind it to different objects on the page.

```js
function setPhraseFontSize() {
  f1 = $("#slider").slider("value");
  f1 = 30 - (f1 * 15);
  f2 = $("#slider").slider("value");
  f2 = 30 + (f2 * 15);
  $("#phrase1").css({
    'font-size': f1 + 'pt'
  });
  $("#phrase2").css({
    'font-size': f2 + 'pt'
  });
}

$("#slider").slider({
  value: 0,
  min: -1,
  max: 1,
  step: 0.1,
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    setPhraseFontSize();
    $('input[name="weighting"]').val($("#slider").slider("value"));

    mydata = $('#feedback').serialize();

    alert("AJAX POST: " + mydata);
  }
});
```

```html
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-MfvZlkHCEqatNoGiOXveE8FIwMzZg4W85qfrfIFBfYc= sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<form id="feedback">
  <input type="hidden" name="phrase1" value="old">
  <input type="hidden" name="phrase2" value="new">
  <input type="hidden" name="weighting">
</form>
<table width="100%">
  <tr style="height:100px">
    <td>
      <div id="phrase1" style="text-align: left;">old</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="phrase2" style="text-align: right;">new</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

I have a pair of phrases and use a UI slider to let the user specify a weighting between them. I have a form with hidden fields and then when the stop even fires I pick up the phrases from this form and the weigting from the slider and then post them back via an ajax call. This all works fine.

Now I want to change the page and instead of having just one pairing per round trip I want to populate the whole page with pairs of phrases and allow the user to work thru each one and choose the weighting as above. Clearly I don't want to duplicate all the code etc but am not at all clear on how I can specify the slider handler once and once only. Ideally the slider would be create once too and then made visible on each pairing as it gets focus. When it fires its stop event it should of course pick up the current pairing and pass those phrases and the appropriate weighting to the ajax call.

What's the best practice way of doing this?

Comment: Either use a classname on all your slider targets, and use that as the jquery selector, or extract your plugin paramters out as a declared object and re-use that

Comment: I would recommend using an MV* framework such as [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) or [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) instead of using jQuery alone to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: What role are the hidden phrase inputs doing?

Comment: Originally it was a round-trip post back to the server and the form/hidden fields are a bit of a hangover from that :(

Comment: The actual app is a laravel app so some of the form objects are generated from that - am looking at MVVW stuff to go with this but it's a steep learning curve ;) Also seems like one needs to be very careful about exposing logic in the client model and also having to do quite a bit of duplication of validation in diff environments (eg JS on the client, PHP on the server) just in case someone hacks the browser code... (but i realise this is language-politics and doesn't belong here!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a common classname on your slider elements is probably the easiest way.

```js
function setPhraseFontSize(sliderNum, value) {
 f1 = 30 - (value * 15);
   $("#phrase" + sliderNum).css({
  'font-size': f1 + 'pt'
   });
}


$(".slider").slider({
  value: 0,
  min: -1,
  max: 1,
  step: 0.1,
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    var sliderNum = $(this).attr("id").replace("slider", "");
    var value = $(this).slider("value");
    setPhraseFontSize(sliderNum, value); // Pass the sliderNum and the value
    $('input[name="weighting'+ sliderNum +'"]').val(value); // Target 'this' instead

    mydata = $('#feedback').serialize();

    alert("AJAX POST: " + mydata);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-MfvZlkHCEqatNoGiOXveE8FIwMzZg4W85qfrfIFBfYc= sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<!-- As per Drew Gaynor's comment - you should really be using a JS MV* framework (or at least some JS template tool) to output this HTML //-->

<form id="feedback">
  <input type="hidden" name="weighting1">
  <input type="hidden" name="weighting2">
</form>

<table width="100%">
  <tr style="height:100px">
    <td>
      <div id="phrase1_old" style="text-align: left;">old</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="phrase1" style="text-align: right;">new</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="slider1" class='slider'></div>

<table width="100%">
  <tr style="height:100px">
    <td>
      <div id="phrase2_old" style="text-align: left;">old</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="phrase2" style="text-align: right;">new</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="slider2" class='slider'></div>
```

If you intend only to have one slider instance at any one time (although this would probably be over-engineering it in all but high amounts of sliders), you would need to bind to the `mouseover` and `mouseout` event on each 'phrase' div, with the `mouseover` event initiating the plugin code, and the `mouseout` event calling `dispose`.

Answer (score 1):

I would create different forms for each pair of phrases, with the same class.

Then you just need to look for the elements in the corresponding context., like this:

```
var currentWeight = $( 'input[name="weighting"]', $( this ) ).val();
```

Where you look for the `input`element in the context of `$( this )`.

To have just one slider, move it to the correct form when the user focus it:

```
$(".feedback").focusin(function() {
  $( this ).append( $("#slider") );
});
```

I leave you a snippet:

```js
function setPhraseFontSize(feedback) {
  f1 = $("#slider").slider("value");
  f1 = 30 - (f1 * 15);
  f2 = $("#slider").slider("value");
  f2 = 30 + (f2 * 15);
  $(".phrase1", feedback).css({
    'font-size': f1 + 'pt'
  });
  $(".phrase2", feedback).css({
    'font-size': f2 + 'pt'
  });
}

$(".feedback").focusin(function() {
  if ($(this).children("#slider").length) return;
  var currentWeight = $( 'input[name="weighting"]', $( this ) ).val();
  $( this ).append( $("#slider") );
  $("#slider").slider( "value", currentWeight );
});

$("#slider").slider({
  value: 0,
  min: -1,
  max: 1,
  step: 0.1,
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    setPhraseFontSize($(this).parent());
    $( 'input[name="weighting"]', $( this ).parent() ).val( $(this).slider("value") );
    mydata = $( this ).parent().serialize();
    alert( "AJAX POST: " + mydata );
  }
});
```

```css
.feedback {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-MfvZlkHCEqatNoGiOXveE8FIwMzZg4W85qfrfIFBfYc= sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ=="
crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<form id="feedback_1" class="feedback" tabindex="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="phrase1" value="old">
  <input type="hidden" name="phrase2" value="new">
  <input type="hidden" name="weighting">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr style="height:100px">
      <td>
        <div class="phrase1" style="text-align: left;">old</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="phrase2" style="text-align: right;">new</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="slider"></div>
</form>
<form id="feedback_2" class="feedback" tabindex="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="phrase1" value="123">
  <input type="hidden" name="phrase2" value="abc">
  <input type="hidden" name="weighting">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr style="height:100px">
      <td>
        <div class="phrase1" style="text-align: left;">123</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="phrase2" style="text-align: right;">abc</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - looks valid but I went with the other one from stumblor and it works just peachy